# From the cluster, cannot download a Python Wheel from the storage account

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

1) We upload a python wheel to the storage account associated with the workspace successfully.
2) In the second step we submit an experiment which runs in the cluster and needs to download and run the package from step 1.

The experiment is able to download the package and run when the storage account is not associated with any VNet. However, when we associate the storage account in Vnets the experiment hangs and eventually fails. This storage account is in two Vnet’s, a, and b. The cluster is also in the Vnet, a.

I don’t know why the cluster cannot download the wheel package when the storage account is in a Vnet. It is our policy to have storage accounts in Vnet’s.

It there something else we are missing? I also checked the container registry setting and its set to ‘allow from everywhere’ (we are using std SKU).

Let me know if any further information is required. Thanks.

Comment: We're aware of this issue and will be rolling out a fix shortly.